# Display function prototype on bracket opening

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm learning java using NetBeans. I want the IDE to display a function prototype after I type '(' so that if I forget some parameters I do not need to erase the function name and '.' and type '.' again in order to see all the functions of that class. How can I turn it on?

Answer (score 2):

It you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> the pop-up list of protypes will be displayed for you.

Comment: Tnaks, that is just what I want.

Comment: +1 to you all guys. Especially for @Dave Webb for use of the <kbd> tag, which was new to me. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

It is probably already on. Have you just tried CTRL+Space ?